# Setting up the ncurses library on Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: c, linux, ncurses

I installed the package `libncurses5-dev` from the Software Center and then checked for the header file :

```
asheesh@ashrj-U32U:~$ ls -l /usr/include/*curses.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 76291 Nov 18  2011 /usr/include/curses.h
lrwxrwxrwx 1 root root     8 Nov 18  2011 /usr/include/ncurses.h -> curses.h
-rw-r--r-- 1 root root 12180 Apr 11  2011 /usr/include/slcurses.h
```

Then, i checked for the library files :

```
asheesh@ashrj-U32U:~$ find /usr/lib/ -name "*curses*"
....
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurses.a
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libcurses.so
/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libncurses.a
....
```

which are <strike>not</strike> present.

<strike>How do i install/make the library files ? Why werent they set up along with the standard package ?</strike>

On simply compiling, i get the error :

```
asheesh@ashrj-U32U:~$ gcc -o screen1 screen1.c -lcurses
asheesh@ashrj-U32U:~$ screen1
No command 'screen1' found, did you mean:
 Command 'screen' from package 'screen' (main)
screen1: command not found
```

How do i use these library files ?

Comment: You should see libncurses in the appropriate linux-gnu-subdirectory for your system.  Try this command instead : `find /usr/lib/ -name "*curses*"`

Comment: @JeffreyTheobald Yes, they are there. How do i use them ? Add the complete directory to the build command ?

Comment: if you're just using C, it's enough to include the header and then add -lncurses to the command line when you're linking with gcc. E.g., `gcc test.c -o test -lncurses`

Comment: @JeffreyTheobald question updated

Comment: you need to use ./screen1 to execute the program since your current directory isn't on the execution path.  I've put all this in an answer, hopefully it helps!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a totally trivial program that uses (barely) the ncurses library:

```
#include "ncurses.h"
int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
  /* Yes, I know, but you don't care about actually using ncurses for the moment */
  return 0;
}
```

Compile with:

```
 gcc test.c -o test -lncurses
```

Then run with:

```
  ./test
```

I've found [this tutorial](http://invisible-island.net/ncurses/ncurses-intro.html) to be a good starting point and [this howto](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/NCURSES-Programming-HOWTO/) to be quite a useful reference when dealing with ncurses.

Comment: [Facepalm to self] Apparently specifying the complete directory was needed, nothing else.

Comment: @AsheeshR: it's not needed if the executable is in your `PATH`. Turns out the current directory *isn't*, for a very good reason ;)